# How to fix error related to reprocuction of a table with flextable and a subsequent plot in RMarkdown

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, flextable

I am getting an error reproducing a table realized with flextable and then a graph with ggplot in RMarkdown

```
 57% [unnamed-chunk-14]Error in `grid.Call.graphics()`:
! not valid character 
Backtrace:
  1. rmarkdown::render("anything", encoding = "UTF-8")
 55. grid:::drawGrob(x)
 57. grid:::drawDetails.text(x, recording = FALSE)
 58. grid:::grid.Call.graphics(...)
```

The code is set mostly like

````
---
title: "c"
author: "x"
date: "x"
output:
  pdf_document:
header-includes:
- \usepackage{subfig}
- |
  ```{=latex}
  \renewcommand\labelitemii{$\circ$}
  ```
    ---

```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE}

tb1 = data %>% filter(!str_detect(fill, 'A'))%>%   
   pairwise_wilcox_test(what ~ fill) %>%
   mutate(lab = paste(p," - ", p.adj.signif), 
   lb = paste0(group1, " vs ", group2, ": p=", lab)) %>% 
   add_xy_position(x = "rsptsk") %>% 
  assign(x = 'pwc_4', value = . , envir = .GlobalEnv) %>% 
  select(2, 3, 6:9) %>% rename('Wilcox test' = statistic, 
  'p-value' = p, 'p.signif' = p.adj.signif, 'Task 1' = group1, 
  'Task 2' = group2) %>% flextable() %>%  
  #merge_v(., j = 'B')%>% 
  set_formatter(values = list("p-value" = p_val_format)) %>%
  set_formatter(values = list("p.adj" = p_val_format)) %>% 
  flextable::font(.,fontname='Corbel', part = 'all') %>% 
  theme_alafoli()

```


```{r echo=FALSE}

tb1 

```



```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, include=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE}
graph1 = data %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(fill, 'A')) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= x, y = y, fill = fill)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = fill)) +
    #scale_color_brewer(palette="Spectral") +
    #scale_color_manual(values = c("A" = "black", "B" = "black", "C" = 'black'))
    #scale_fill_manual(values=c("blue", "cyan4", 'red')) + 
    #scale_colour_manual(values= c(rep('black', 3))) +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour= rsptsk), method = "lm", formula = y ~ x) + 
  #or alternatively poly(x, 2)
  #geom_smooth(aes(colour= rsptsk), method = "lm", formula = y ~ poly(x, 2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=c(c("lightcyan", "mistyrose",  "cornsilk"))) +
  #geom_smooth(aes(colour= rsptsk), method = "lm", formula = map(seq(1:5), \(i) {y ~ poly(x, i)})) +
  labs(title = "Title",x = "x", y = "y") +   theme_classic() + theme(legend.title=element_blank(), 
  text=element_text(size= 11, family= "Corbel"))

```


```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, paged.print=FALSE}

graph1

```
````

I found something here as follows ([https://www.programmingr.com/r-error-messages/error-in-call-graphicsc_palette2-callc_palette2-null-invalid-graphics-state/#:~:text=This%20error%20message%20occurs%20when%20using%20the%20ggplot,occurs%2C%20do%20a%20reset%20using%20the%20dev.off%20function.](https://www.programmingr.com/r-error-messages/error-in-call-graphicsc_palette2-callc_palette2-null-invalid-graphics-state/#:%7E:text=This%20error%20message%20occurs%20when%20using%20the%20ggplot,occurs%2C%20do%20a%20reset%20using%20the%20dev.off%20function.)) that to correct this might serve a `dev.off()` but I do not know how and where to add this. Can anyone help with this?